# Parsing XHTML in a jQuery success callback doesn't work in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Here is a simple callback that is processed on a successful return from the Ajax

```
   Entropy . eBookHandler . fetchPageHandler = function ( data, status, request ) 
    { var container = jQuery ( this ); 
      var xhtml = jQuery ( data );
      var body = xhtml . find ( "body" );
      var div = body . children ( "div" );
      var clone = div . clone ( true );
      var content = container . children ( );
      if ( 0 < content . length )
       content . replaceWith ( clone );
      else
       container . prepend ( clone );

      Entropy . eBookHandler . bindContentHandlers ( );
    };
```

This is invoked after execution of the following jQuery .ajax method:

```
    jQuery . ajax 
        ( { context: container, type: 'GET',  url: page, 
            dataType: 'xml', async: true, cache: false, 
            timeout: 10000, 
            success: Entropy. eBookHandler.fetchPageHandler,
            error: Entropy.eBookHandler.ajaxErrorHandler 
        } );
```

**This works perfectly in all browsers except the IE series where the XHTML fragment requested is not loaded into the "host"DOM.**  The clone method is needed because the local DOM and that loaded as xhtml are of course different.

It's pretty clear that IE is behaving differently from all the other browsers, how do we fix this? (The return XHTML content verifies as XHTML 1.0 Exact at W3C)

I found a suggestion which is to treat IE separately by adding the following parenthesis:

```
if( jQuery.browser.msie)
{ var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
  xmlDoc.loadXML(data);
  xhtml = xmlDoc;
}
```

So will this work, or is there one code sequence that will work for all browsers?

Comment: Place a `debugger;` at the beginning of `fetchPageHandler` and inspect step by step. In IE and in an other browser, you will find immediately where the difference comes from.

Comment: Appreciate your reply, but I don't have ready access to a Windows PC (who would want one given a choice?). I have a non-programmewr friend who can step though using Skype / IE 9 but that's a VERY slow process!

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a known issue with IE. I tried simmilar code with for example the simpler: container . html ( body . html ( ) ); or container [0] . innerHTML = body [ 0 ]  .innerHTML . Both of these work flawlessly in all browsers except IE ... Clearly the data object must be different in the two cases ...